# github.com IDE app for mac

Tags: git, macos, github

Hello all im new to Github.com, and i think its really hard to learn all the commandos and use the terminal etc. so i just wanna know if there was a app for uploading protject to github :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best visual client for Git on Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455698/best-visual-client-for-git-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: "I'm new to Github.com" I think you mean that you're new to *Git*; what you should be looking for is to learn to use Git (or to find a GUI you like for it). Github is just a hosting provider.

Answer (score 5):

I've used GitX - http://gitx.frim.nl for a while. It's not exactly a GitHub client, but it works all the same.

Git Tower - http://www.git-tower.com is a relatively new client in beta and looks very promising.

Answer (score 3):

There's an official one from Github now, called "[Github for Mac](http://mac.github.com/)"!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are any applications that are stable yet. Learning to use the terminal can be a bit overwhelming at first, but it's worth it. You get a lot of power from it :)

Keep a cheat sheet by your desk for the most common commands and follow the guide at GitHub.com to learn more about Git.

Answer (score 1):

there is a kickstart project for a github client: Hubcap

http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1487030260/hubcap-a-github-client-for-mac-os-x
https://github.com/blog/761-hubcap-a-socially-aware-github-mac-app

here is another github client [hubboard](http://github.com/lukaszkorecki/hubboard)